# How can I add a directory to the search path of GNU Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that looks something like this:

```
include anotherFile.mk

all:
    someStuff
```

The file `anotherFile.mk` is like this:

```
include yetAnotherFile.mk
export SOME_VAR = 93
```

The problem is that `anotherFile.mk` and `yetAnotherFile.mk` are in a different directory from my Makefile.  So my makefile can't just be changed to this:

```
include $(OTHER_PROJECT_PATH)/anotherFile.mk

all:
    someStuff
```

The problem with this approach is that the include statement in `anotherFile.mk` will fail because it will be searching in the current directory.

A partial solution that I found is to pass the `--include-dir=$OTHER_PROJECT_PATH` flag to the invocation of make, but that's a bit user-unfriendly.

So my question is: Is there something I can put inside my makefile that will add to the directories that make searches for when executing an `include`?  Something like `MAKE_INCLUDE_DIRS += $(OTHER_PROJECT_PATH)`

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly there doesn't seem to be a good answer to that question. Forcing `.INCLUDE_DIR` doesn't help and there doesn't seem to be any way around invoking `make` with `--include-dir=$OTHER_PROJECT_PATH`.

It is however possible to put the appropriate recursive make invocation inside the makefile but, in order to get it to work for all reasonable cases it quickly becomes too complicated to be worth it. In summary it requires:

- a top level condition to check if the `OTHER_PROJECT_PATH` is in `.INCLUDE_DIR`
- the appropriate target with the recipe invoking make recursively
- possibly additional targets if there are multiple command goals
- the real make file enclosed in the `else` part of the conditional

You Makefile would look like this:

```
OTHER_PROJECT_PATH := other
ifeq (,$(filter $(OTHER_PROJECT_PATH), $(.INCLUDE_DIRS)))
# this is the mechanism to add the include dir in a recursive make
$(or $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)),all):
    $(MAKE) -I$(OTHER_PROJECT_PATH) $(MAKECMDGOALS)
# add empty targets for additional goals if needed
ifneq (,$(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
$(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS)):
endif
else
# this is where the real makefile starts
all more:
    echo $@: $< $^
include a.mak
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

It still does not seem possible from a makefile, but if you have a script that sets up environment variables, you can use MAKEFLAGS (e.g. export MAKEFLAGS=I/your/path ordentlich on Linux, or SET on Windows)